# Assign Case Statement Value to Variable

Tags: sql, case

I'm writing a function for PPK.  I can get this Case statement to work if I eliminate the "END AS @PPK", but I get a syntax error when I try to assign the final result to my variable.  Can anybody tell me what I've got wrong here:  Thanks!

```
DECLARE @USL AS DECIMAL(5,2)
DECLARE @LSL AS DECIMAL(5,2)
DECLARE @AVG AS DECIMAL(5,2)
DECLARE @SDEV AS DECIMAL(5,2)

SET @USL = 6.143
SET @LSL = 2.9382
SET @AVG = 4.1
SET @SDEV = 1.6

DECLARE @PPK DECIMAL(5,2)

DECLARE @VAL1 DECIMAL(5,2)
DECLARE @VAL2 DECIMAL(5,2)

SET @VAL1 = (@USL - @AVG)/(3*@SDEV)
SET @VAL2 = (@AVG - @LSL)/(3*@SDEV)
SELECT @VAL1
SELECT @VAL2

SELECT CASE
    WHEN @VAL1 < @VAL2
    THEN @VAL1
    ELSE @VAL2 END
--END AS @PPK
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @PPK = CASE
    WHEN @VAL1 < @VAL2
    THEN @VAL1
    ELSE @VAL2 END
```